# Dold's theorem, algebraic topology

Tags: algebraic-topology

I have encountered a theorem in topology, in some notes, but with no precise formulation and with a name: *Dold's theorem*. Google wasn't able to find anything similar to this. So, the theorem states the following:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces, of which $X$ is path-connected and it holds $\pi_1(X)=\pi_2(X)=....=\pi_n(X)=0$. Let $G$ act on $X$ and on $Y$, and let the action of $G$ to $Y$ be free, and $\dim(Y) \leq n$. Then, there is no $G$-equivariant mapping $f:X \to Y$.

A mapping is $G$-invariant if it acts according to some action, precisely, if $f:X \to Y$ and $G$ acts on $X$ and $Y$, then for all $x$ it holds $f(g \circ x) = g \circ f(x)$.

If anything like this you have seen, please write.

Comment: It seems to be this paper: https://books.google.cz/books?id=W-AbCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA65&lpg=PA65&dq=Albrecht+Dold,+Simple+proofs+of+some+Borsuk-Ulam+results,&source=bl&ots=OPfaDiCnRX&sig=MqVffQPr8VF0QW9aWBtDarM86Ns&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ta5qVcesE8bwUq2xg9AP&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=Albrecht%20Dold%2C%20Simple%20proofs%20of%20some%20Borsuk-Ulam%20results%2C&f=false

Comment: Is this theorem really true as stated? Let $X=Y=*$ and $G$ the trivial group. Then the stated hypotheses are verified, but there is a map $* \to *$...